# Does inside "if" statement change running time of algorithm?

Tags: big-o, time-complexity

I have written the running time based on my calculation in red color on the picture. But I don't know what would be for that IF statement as well as it's body's running time. Will that IF condition's running time would be `n x n` ? Because each time in the inner loop, it would be evaluated. Isn't it? What about it's body's?

[image]

Comment: 4 = N*M; 5 = N; 6 = 1; 7=1 ;8=1;

Comment: Thanks. But did you mistakenly swapped 4 and 5? I mean, 4 is M and 5 is MxN ?

Comment: I think it is just a difference in terms/notation. 5 itself has a runtime of N. However, it is executed M times. 4 is N * M because it iterates M and at each iteration it execute step 5 (which is N). 6 is 1 because it is just an if (the if gets checked N*M times). ect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take into account *two* different parameters, *m* and *n*. The outermost loop executes *m* times, and the inner loop executes *n* times. The complexity, therefore, is θ(*mn*).

Note that the `if`-statement and its body are executed in constant time.

Comment: Thank you. So, 4 = m, 5 = m*n, 6 = 1, 7 = 1, 8 = 1. Am I right?

Comment: @VppMan Well depending on the convention your using, it might make more sense to say 5 = n. The if-statement would then be reached m*n times.

Comment: Am sorry. But I didn't got you.

Comment: @VppMan Line 5 loops *n* times, so doesn't it make more sense to say 5 = n?

Comment: Oh, you mean, 4 = m, 5 = n, 6 = m*n, 7 = 1, 8 = 1. Isn't it?

Comment: The body of the IF would be executed for once only. Isn't it? I mean, when the condition matches only, we could say that it was executed. Isn't it?

Comment: @VppMan We can't know *exactly* how many times the body will be executed because we don't know what the arrays are. However, we know that the body only takes constant time to execute, so it shouldn't affect the overall complexity.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. So, we could just mention that it is `1` or `m * n`. Right? It would be more appropriate if we use `m*n`, isn't it?

Comment: @VppMan Again, it depends on what convention you are using. If you mean "how many times does this line get *reached*", then yes, `m*n` is more accurate.

Comment: If there was a function call inside the above code, we will get the total time of that function's and adds it up too?

Comment: @VppMan Yes, you would have to.

Comment: ok thanks. Can you please take a look at this: http://i.imgur.com/Q1ZiWo3.png. That `FindMatchingPairs()` is the above code that I have shown in this question. Am I doing it in the right track? The complexity would be: `O(a + m*n)` ? Is it correct? These things are giving heavy headache! :(

Comment: @arshajii: I would clarify this answer: if something is known about the distribution of data in the arrays, then one can apply those to determine the _expected_ complexity of lines 7 and 8, though that no longer falls under the "big O notation".